# How can I save my hardcore map after I die?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My brother jumped into the voice of the doom in my Hardcore Creative map.
I didn't press the ΄΄**Delete This World**΄΄ button yet.

Comment: To prevent this in the future, open your saves folder when you see the death screen, then copy the world to a safe location

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of a Hardcore Creative Map, and how exactly did you manage to die in Creative?

Comment: As a general rule in the games that have "Hardcore mode", if you're not prepared to deal with the consequences of dying, you shouldn't be playing hardcore.

Comment: This will probably never be read, but can your explain what the "voice of the doom" is? Is that a typo?

Answer (score 7):

As you probably know, hardcore mode is the same as hard mode but when you die your world is deleted.

When you die in hardcore mode you are given this game over screen.

[image: Hardcore death screen]

If you clicked the <kbd>Delete world</kbd> button your world is gone, kapoosh. But you might be in luck.

The can retrieve this is if you revert the `saves` folder to a previous version. To do this you have to locate your `saves` folder.

It can be found in the directory: `%appdata%\.minecraft\saves`

Once you have found the `saves` folder right click on it and select `Restore previous versions`. Select the latest version before you died and restore it.

Your world should return to its previous state, before you died.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to maintain backups of your worlds regardless. You never know what could happen...

Answer (score 2):

After dieing, choose to go into spectator mode instead of deleting the world (for obvious reasons). Then open the world to LAN and set <kbd>cheats enabled</kbd> to `ON`.

Run the command `/gamemode survival`.
Save and exit.

You should now be able to load your world again and you will be in survival mode, cheats will be disabled and your next death will be permanent (unless you follow these steps again).

*Note: I tested this in 1.14.4, it may not work in previous versions*

Answer (score 0):

Don't click the "Delete World" button instead close out Minecraft and write down the seed before you make your world.